# viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind crashes app searching for UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter (which I'm not requesting)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I'm using Xcode 8.2, and getting the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier Header - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Here is the function causing the issue:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
  return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath)
}
```

Initially it was having an issue finding UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, but now seems to be stuck on the footer view, which is odd because I haven't actually activated it in Interface Builder:

[image: Image of IB]

The reuse identifier for the supplementary (collection reusable view) matches the string in the function. I've tried removing the app from the simulator to no avail. I'm not using any separate nibs or anything out of the ordinary.

I'd done this before in the past with no issue, not sure if this is an Xcode bug or if I've gone awry somewhere.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

Thanks to the replies and comments I attempted to add the following to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName:"Header", bundle: Bundle.main), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier:"Header")
```

Which prompted an additional error:

`Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewC‌​ategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UI‌​Kit-3600.5.2/UIColle‌​ctionView.m:4922`

**Resolved**

Sorry folks. It was a stupid oversight on my part.
@matt pointed out that I'd implemented an erroneous method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
```

When I meant to implement:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
```

Basically, that's where all the confusion stemmed from.

Kindly ignore me. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you calling ```register(_:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)```?

Comment: @EricKenny no. Should I be?

Comment: Yes, in ```viewDidLoad```
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618101-register

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Please see the answer below where I've now added this but am seeing an additional error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
   layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
   referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
```

Delete that method. You have no footer.

Also you have said

```
self.collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName:"Header", bundle: Bundle.main), 
    forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, 
    withReuseIdentifier:"Header")
```

Delete that line. You must not register when you are getting your object from the storyboard, and in any case you have no nib named "Header".

Your app will then launch without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to register nib in `viewDidLoad()`

```
 self.collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName:"Header", bundle: Bundle.main), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier:"Header")
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added this, and now am getting an additional error: `Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UICollectionView.m:4922`

Comment: However, is it not strange that the initial error is referring to a footer view even though it's not selected in IB?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check the another view exists at the root level.

[image]